# Powershell v2 does not return the object of a function

Tags: function, object, powershell, return

I have a function that tests if a path or multiple paths are valid and if they exist. Now I have created a custom PSObject with several arrays and want the function to return the object. But it seems to return just an Array instead of the original custom Object. The Debugger of Powershell ISE Shows that within the function the object exists. What have I done wrong?

This is my code

```
function Validate-Path
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    Param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Array]$Inputpaths
    )
        $Ispathvalid=test-path $Inputpaths -IsValid
        $Validpaths=@()
        $Invalidpaths=@()

        $counter=0
        foreach ($item in $Ispathvalid)
        {
            if($Ispathvalid[$counter] -eq $true)
            {
                $Validpaths+=$Inputpaths[$counter] 
            }
            else
            {
                $Invalidpaths+=$Inputpaths[$counter] 
            }
            $counter++

        }

        $Doespathexist=test-path $Validpaths
        $Testvalue=$true
        $Existingpaths=@()
        $NonExistingpaths=@()
        $counter=0
        foreach ($item in $Validpaths)
        {
            if($Doespathexist[$counter] -eq $true)
            {
                $Existingpaths+=$Validpaths[$counter] 
            }
            else
            {
                $NonExistingpaths+=$Validpaths[$counter]
            }
            $counter++

        }

        $object = New-Object  PSObject 
        $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Existingpaths -Value $Existingpaths
        $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NonExistingpaths -Value $NonExistingpaths
        $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Validpaths -Value $Validpaths
        $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Invalidpaths -Value $Invalidpaths

        return $object
}
```

Comment: Code works for me. What is the output of `$PSVersionTable` on your system.

Comment: Works for me too. Can you show how you are calling it, and the output that is produced?

Answer (score 0):

Use `PSCustomObject` instead of `PSObject`.

Change this line:

```
$object = New-Object  PSObject
```

To this:

```
$object = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, since `PSObject` is just an abbreviation for `PSCustomObject`.